Finding an analytical solution to a particular class of second order ODEs
Let
$$\ddot{y}+f(x)y=0$$
Be a differential equation such that $\{y,f\}\subseteq\mathcal{C}^\infty$. We make the substitution $y=e^{u(x)}$ to get:
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}e^{u(x)}+f(x)e^{u(x)}=0$$
Or
$$(\ddot{u}(x)+\dot{u}(x)^2)e^{u(x)}+f(x)e^{u(x)}=0$$
Or, dividing by $e^{u(x)}$
$$\ddot{u}(x)+\dot{u}(x)^2=-f(x)$$
Which can be turned into a first order, non-linear ODE by order reduction $p(x)=\dot{u}(x)$
$$\dot{p}(x)+p(x)^2=-f(x)$$
Can this be used to find an analytical solution to the ODE?

You probably want $p(x) = \dot{u}(x)$, right?

Yes, sorry. I edited it already.

@Marco Yes! At least locally.

Your last equation is a Riccati equation. One usually solves it via the substitution $u=v'/v$, which transforms it into the linear ODE $v''+f(x)v=0$...

@Gonçalo Huh... Is there some kind of constraint that prevents analitycal solutions for this kind of equation? Maybe this is a differential analogue for Abel-Ruffinni limit?

I will change the equation very slightly to the following.
$$
y''(t)=f(t)y(t)
$$
A symbolic solution to such an equation is the following...
$$
y(t) = y_{0}+y_{1}t + \sum^{\infty}_{a=1} \int_{T^{a}(t)} (y_{0}+y_{1}\tau_{a})(t-\tau_{1})f(\tau_{a})\prod_{r=1}^{a-1}f(\tau_{r})(\tau_{r}-\tau_{r+1}) d\tau^{a}
$$
(with an abuse of notation where if the limit of product is less then the start simply dont compute the product this only pertains to when a=1) Where $y_{0}$ and $y_{1}$ are the value of the solution and its derivitive at 0 respectively, and $T^{a}(t)$ is the domain of integration defined as following.
$$
T^{a}(t) = \{(\tau_{1},\cdots,\tau_{a}) \; | \; t>\tau_{1}>\cdots>\tau_{a}>0\}
$$
$T^{a}(t)$ is essentially an "a"-dimensional triangular region with base length of $t$ with the corner at the origin, as well $T^{1}(t)$ is just the interval $[0,t]$. Hence, the sum is a sum of increasingly high dimensional integrals. If one chooses a function $f(t)$ is is possible to find a general expression for the "a"-th term. Proof of its validity goes as follows.
$$
\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}} \int_{T^{a}(t)} (y_{0}+y_{1}\tau_{a})(t-\tau_{1})f(\tau_{a})\prod_{r=1}^{a-1}f(\tau_{r})(\tau_{r}-\tau_{r+1}) d\tau^{a} = \frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}} \int_{0}^{t} (t-\tau_{1})F(\tau_{1})d\tau_{1} \cdots
$$
$$
\cdots = \frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}\int^{t}_{0}\int^{\tau_{1}}_{0}F(\tau_{2})d\tau_{2}d\tau_{1} = F(t) = f(t)\int_{T^{a-1}(t)} (y_{0}+y_{1}\tau_{a-1})(t-\tau_{1})f(\tau_{a-1})\prod_{r=1}^{a-2}f(\tau_{r})(\tau_{r}-\tau_{r+1}) d\tau^{a-1}
$$
This expression is valid for any $a$ but special care needs to be taken for the first term where we have...
$$
\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}\int^{t}_{0}(y_0+y_{1}\tau)(t-\tau)f(\tau)d\tau = \frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}\int^{t}_{0}\int^{\tau_{1}}_{0}(y_0+y_{1}\tau_{2})f(\tau_{2})d\tau_{2}d\tau_{2} = (y_{0}+y_{1}t)f(t)
$$
Using these expressions we have that...
$$
\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}y(t) = (y_{0}+y_{1}t)f(t) + f(t)\sum^{\infty}_{a=2}\int_{T^{a-1}(t)} (y_{0}+y_{1}\tau_{a-1})(t-\tau_{1})f(\tau_{a-1})\prod_{r=1}^{a-2}f(\tau_{r})(\tau_{r}-\tau_{r+1}) d\tau^{a-1} = f(t) \left( y_{0}+y_{1}t + \sum^{\infty}_{a=1} \int_{T^{a}(t)} (y_{0}+y_{1}\tau_{a})(t-\tau_{1})f(\tau_{a})\prod_{r=1}^{a-1}f(\tau_{r})(\tau_{r}-\tau_{r+1}) d\tau^{a} \right) = f(t)y(t)
$$
Hence the solution given is the solution to the differential equation.
The specific form is that of a solution IVP but the $y_{0}$ and $y_{1}$ can be taken to be general constansts and the expression seperated to give a general solution of the form.
$$
y(t) = ay_{1}(t)+by_{2}(t)
$$
$$
y_{1}(t) = 1+\sum^{\infty}_{a=1} \int_{T^{a}(t)}(t-\tau_{1})f(\tau_{a})\prod_{r=1}^{a-1}f(\tau_{r})(\tau_{r}-\tau_{r+1}) d\tau^{a}
$$
$$
y_{2}(t) = t+\sum^{\infty}_{a=1} \int_{T^{a}(t)}(t-\tau_{1})\tau_{a}f(\tau_{a})\prod_{r=1}^{a-1}f(\tau_{r})(\tau_{r}-\tau_{r+1}) d\tau^{a}
$$
Depending on f(t) it could be very difficult to find an expression for the "a"-th term that doesn't involve integrals, but at least you can write it down.

Hi, @AidanR.S., thank you for your interesting answer! Could you please clarify what method of integration did you use to get from the nested integral $\int_{T^a(t)}\phi(f,t,\tau_1,...,\tau_a)d\tau^a$ to the (apparently) unnested one $\int_0^t(t-\tau_1)F(\tau_1)d\tau_1(...)$? If i understood correctly, you got there by some sort of integration.

Also, i'm getting $\int_0^t(y_0+y_1\tau_1)(t-\tau_1)f(\tau_1)$$\prod_{r=1}^0f(\tau_r)(\tau_r-\tau_{r+1})d\tau_1$
for the first term of the summation, so there's something wrong with your formulation (notice the indexing in the productory).

@SimónFlavioIbañez Yes, I should have mentioned that there is some abuse of notation with product when the limit is greater then the starting value you just dont do the product. It was just so the first term doesnt have to be writen out. The is no integral step that is hidden you simply do the $\tau_{1}$ integration first and the rest of the integrals amount to some function in $\tau_{1}$ that I called $F(\tau_{1})$. You can see the exact definition of what $F(\tau_{1})$ is in the last equality.

Ah. I see. Thanks for the clarification. I'll check my results again later. Also, may i suggest the notation $F(\tau_1,...,\tau_n)$ for speaking about functions of multiple variables? It can be a significant gain in readability.

@SimónFlavioIbañez Well when collapsing the integrals the only variable that the function is of is $\tau_{1}$ as all the variables of integration get integrated away. But I am sorry for the confusion.

Whoa! This works perfectly!!! The exact symbolic solution i was looking for!!!

AidanR.S. may i ask how did you find this solution? Is there some reference about it somewhere? Did you find the solution yourself? If its the latter i would like to contact you somehow. Thanks!

@SimónFlavioIbañez Yes I did find it my self. The solution is only a special case of a general solution for all linear ODE that I also found myself. It comes from a strange intersection of fixed point expansions in abstract operator spaces, and was inspired by the work of Freeman Dyson in quantum field theory. You can email me at aidanrsgarlato@gmail.com if you'd like and I can share with you the full paper.

The final equation,
$$p' + p^2 = -f ,$$
is a Riccati equation. But as Gonçalo pointed out in the comments, the standard method for solving a Riccati equation is to change variable via $p(x) = \frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}$, which transforms the equation back into your original, linear equation
$$y'' + f y = 0.$$
This equation can, however, be solved readily for some special classes of $f$.

If $f$ is constant, the equation is constant-coefficient and so can be solved in terms of elementary functions in the usual way.
If $f$ is a power function, say, $f(x) = a x^b$, $b \neq -2$, a suitable change of variables transforms the equation into the Bessel equation of order $\frac1{b + 2}$. (If $b = 1$, the equation is up to a change of variables the Airy equation).
For $f(x)$ is an exponential function, a change of variables again transforms the equation into the Bessel equation of order $0$.
If $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, its solutions are parabolic cylinder functions.
If $f(x)=a-2q\cos(2x)$, its solutions are Mathieu functions.

